# Only bottom corners rounded

Tags: ios, swift, textview, rounded-corners

I have a textview below a tableView, both same Backgroundcolor so it appears as if its one View. Now I want the bottom corners of the textview to be rounded, but not the top ones (cause then you could see a gap between the textview and tableview). I found some answers on here, but somehow it just makes the bottom left corner rounded, not the right one? I also tried changing the order inside the Array, didn't work. Then I tried just the left corner, worked. But only the right corner didn't work?!  Here is what I have at the moment

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.eventDescription.frame
    rectShape.position = self.eventDescription.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.eventDescription.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath




    self.eventDescription.layer.mask = rectShape
```

Comment: May be beacause you passed `byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight]` ?

Comment: yes but I also tried only byRoundingCorners: .BottomLeft which worked perfectly, but byRoundingCorners: .BottomRight didn't do anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working code for me just check the constraints which you have added.

```
        let maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.button.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.BottomLeft, .BottomRight]), cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0))
        let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.button.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
        self.button.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

[image]

Comment: It works if I set the width to a specific width.. but normally I wanted to set the trailing space to 10.. I checked your answer as right, but do you maybe know how I can do that with the trailing space constraint?

Comment: when I put your code into viewDidAppear, it works also with trailing space constraints.. but still it's not perfect, because you can see the changing process... when I put it into the viewWillAppear, I have the same problem like before -.-